# the windows memory allocation can not change automatically in virtual env

Tags: windows, memory, kvm-switch

The vm will allocate all memory in compute node when I boot a 2C16G40G windows vm, and I have already enable balloon in vm and set memory allocation manually. In contrast, The memory of Linux vm can be allocated automatically by balloon.

Is it a balloon of windows vm's bug in kvm/qemu or my incorrect configurations?

```
root@cmp001:/# virsh version
Compiled against library: libvirt 6.0.0
Using library: libvirt 6.0.0
Using API: QEMU 6.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 4.2.1

root@cmp001:~# virsh qemu-monitor-command instance-000112f4 --hmp "info balloon"
balloon: actual=16384

root@cmp001:~# top -p 8977
top - 10:12:37 up 14 days, 16:05,  1 user,  load average: 5.12, 5.29, 5.09
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.6 us,  5.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13188148+total, 23065860 free, 88282144 used, 20533472 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8388604 total,  7387032 free,  1001572 used. 38870928 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                               
 8977 libvirt+  20   0 18.316g 0.015t  30668 S   9.7 12.5   1938:22 qemu-system-x86                                                                       

root@cmp001:~# virsh qemu-monitor-command instance-000112f4 --hmp "balloon 8192"

root@cmp001:~# virsh qemu-monitor-command instance-000112f4 --hmp "info balloon"
balloon: actual=8192

root@cmp001:~# virsh dumpxml instance-000112f4
  <memory unit='KiB'>16777216</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>

root@cmp001:~# top -p 8977
top - 10:24:45 up 14 days, 16:17,  2 users,  load average: 7.90, 6.90, 6.03
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.6 us,  5.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13188148+total, 23020384 free, 88319936 used, 20541164 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8388604 total,  7395992 free,   992612 used. 38826532 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                               
 8977 libvirt+  20   0 18.316g 7.772g  30668 S   6.7  6.2   1940:13 qemu-system-x86
```

Comment: Ram changes require a reboot for windows. same with vcpu/vcores. you can add additional storage, and often increase storage without a reboot (as long as you don't need to change the partition table type),

Comment: @FrankThomas Hi Frank,the issue I found is the windows vm that I boot with 2C16G40G will allocate all memory in compute node, and it could only set memory allocation manually with `virsh qemu-monitor-command <vm-id> --hmp "balloon 8192"` to change actual memory usage in compute node. 
In the meantime, the reduced memory in compute node will be increase in the inner windows system. Is it should be allocate memory automatically like Linux vm?